# animateKeyframes with repeat and delay does not work as expected

Tags: ios, animation, swift3

I'm creating a simple left to right animation for a label using key frames but when the animation repeats, the delay is ignored.

The first time it executes, the delay of 3 seconds has an effect, but when the animation repeats, the delay is ignored. This causes the animation to re-start immediately after it ends.

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 10, delay: 3, options: [.calculationModePaced, .repeat], animations: {
    let xDist = self.Label_ArtistAlbum2.frame.origin.x

    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.1, animations: {
        self.Label_ArtistAlbum2.frame.origin.x = self.Label_ArtistAlbum2.frame.origin.x - (xDist * 0.1)
    })

    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.9, relativeDuration: 0.1, animations: {
        self.Label_ArtistAlbum2.frame.origin.x = 0
    })
}, completion: nil)
```

I've tried adding an extra keyframe at the end however this has no effect even with the altered times:

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 10, delay: 3, options: [.calculationModePaced, .repeat], animations: {
    let xDist = self.Label_ArtistAlbum2.frame.origin.x

    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.1, animations: {
        self.Label_ArtistAlbum2.frame.origin.x = self.Label_ArtistAlbum2.frame.origin.x - (xDist * 0.1)
    })

    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.1, relativeDuration: 0.7, animations: {
        self.Label_ArtistAlbum2.frame.origin.x = 0
    })

    //attempted pause - does not appear to work perhaps since the position is unchanged?
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.8, relativeDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        self.Label_ArtistAlbum2.frame.origin.x = 0
    })
}, completion: nil)
```

If the delay will not be repeated along with the rest of the animation, how can I create a pause before the entire animation repeats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a lot of testing on this issue and have found what I believe is the problem.

I think that the animation option for the Curve is my issue.
In my case choosing

**calculationModePaced**

has the effect of recalculating my keyframe parameters and not guaranteeing to hit any of them except the beginning and end. All intermediate keyframes become 'suggestions'.
You can't create a pause at the end because the keyframe is 'consumed' when recalculating and does not stand on it's own.

I changed to calculationModeLinear and got the keyframes I expected, and the pause too.
However, it is as smooth as I would like so I'll have to keep tinkering...

Apple's docs are here - they're descriptive but could really use some graphics and/or examples:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview?language=swift

A good graph of the curves can be found here: https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios7-day-by-day-day-11-uiview-key-frame-animations

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem for animating a loading view. I solved it this way:

I created an enum for the steps in the animation

```
private enum TriangleToAnimate {
    case one
    case two
    case three
    case pause
}
```

I have my variables

```
private var triangleViewToFireCount = TriangleToAnimate.one
var triangle1View : TriangleView
var triangle2View : TriangleView
var triangle3View : TriangleView
```

I start a timer to run each animation

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.33, target: self, selector: #selector(LoadingView.timerFire), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

For the selector I have a fire method. In the method I have a switch for each of the enum cases

```
func timerFire(){
    let anim = createAnimation()
    switch triangleViewToFireCount {
    case .one:
        triangle1View.layer.add(anim, forKey: "transform")
        triangleViewToFireCount = .two
    case .two:
        triangle2View.layer.add(anim, forKey: "transform")
        triangleViewToFireCount = .three
    case .three:
        triangle3View.layer.add(anim, forKey: "transform")
        triangleViewToFireCount = .pause
    default:
        triangleViewToFireCount = .one
    }
}
```

This is the code how I created the animation as a keyframe

```
func createAnimation() -> CAKeyframeAnimation{
    let tr = CATransform3DIdentity
    let orignalScale = CATransform3DScale(tr, 1, 1, 1)
    let doubleScale = CATransform3DScale(tr, 2, 2, 1)
    let keyAn = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
    keyAn.keyTimes = [0, 0.1, 0.6]
    keyAn.duration = 1
    keyAn.values = [orignalScale,doubleScale,orignalScale]
    keyAn.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
    return keyAn
}
```